# How can I pass the model from Login success in Login.cshtml to _layout.cshtml in Razerpages, for dynamically add side bar menu in _Layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

I have two classes such as `clsGEN_GROUP_MENU` and `clsSidebarMenu`  and I have bind `clsSidebarMenu` property during login time in, but I can't pass the model to _Layout.cshtml.

```
public class clsSidebarMenu
{
        public clsSidebarMenu()
        {
            MenuItems = new List<clsGEN_GROUP_MENU>();
        }
        public List<clsGEN_GROUP_MENU> MenuItems { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class clsGEN_GROUP_MENU
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 id { get; set; }
    public string Group_Code { get; set; }
    public  string? ModuleName { get; set; }
    public string? Arb_menu_name { get; set; }
    public string? menu_name { get; set; }
    public int? level { get; set; }
    public int? Visible { get; set; }
    public int? Enabled { get; set; }
    public Int64? parent_id { get; set; }
    
 }
```

Here I have bind the `clsSidebarMenu` in during Login in Login.cshtml like these, it is the `OnPost` method in Login.cshtml

```
public async Task< IActionResult> OnPost(clsGEN_USER_DEMO LogginUser)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                clsGEN_USER_DEMO logged = bizmagnetServices.fnCheckLoginCridentials(LogginUser);
                if(logged!=null)
                {
                    clsSidebarMenu SidebarMenu = new clsSidebarMenu();
                    SidebarMenu.MenuItems = bizmagnetServices.fnGetMenuList();//Here it bind Menu item from Database
                    var claims = new List<Claim>
                    {
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,LogginUser.USER_CODE),
                        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,LogginUser.USER_CODE),
                        new Claim("Department","Sales")
                        
                    };
                    var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims,"MyCookieAuth");
                    ClaimsPrincipal claimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
                    var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
                    {
                        IsPersistent=LogginUser.RememberMe
                    };
                    await HttpContext.SignInAsync("MyCookieAuth",claimsPrincipal, authProperties);
                    return RedirectToPage("/Dashboard");//Here it Redirect to Dashboard while Login Success
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("", "The user name or password provided is incorrect.");
                }
            }
            return Page();
        }
```

Here it shows get the menu list from database and it redirects to Dashboard, but I want to pass that `SidebarMenu` to _Layout.cshtml.

[Here is the Image Showing Project Structure, Please Take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iD8RJ.png)

[Here I have Added Layout images please take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/arlTl.png)

[Here it show I iterate through loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zigYy.png)

[Here it Shows Error Message please go through it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hmnmb.png)

Answer (score 0):

Use `ViewData` and `JsonSerializer` to pass data from PageModel in _Layout.

**Login.csthml.cs**

```
    [BindProperty]
    public clsSidebarMenu model { get; set; }


    [BindProperty]
    public clsGEN_GROUP_MENU cgm { get; set; }

//....other code.....

public async Task< IActionResult> OnPost(clsGEN_USER_DEMO LogginUser)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                clsGEN_USER_DEMO logged = bizmagnetServices.fnCheckLoginCridentials(LogginUser);
                if(logged!=null)
                {
                    clsSidebarMenu SidebarMenu = new clsSidebarMenu();
                    SidebarMenu.MenuItems = bizmagnetServices.fnGetMenuList();//Here it bind Menu item from Database
                    
                   //after you bind data from database,use JsonSerializer to pass data.
                      ViewData["data"] = JsonSerializer.Serialize(SidebarMenu);

                        var claims = new List<Claim>
                        {
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name,LogginUser.USER_CODE),
                            new Claim(ClaimTypes.Email,LogginUser.USER_CODE),
                            new Claim("Department","Sales")
                            
                        };
                 //.........
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
@using System.Text.Json;

@{
    var data = ViewData["data"] as string;
    var modelList = new RazorPageIdentity.Pages.LoginModel.clsSidebarMenu();
    if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data))
    {
         modelList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<RazorPageIdentity.Pages.LoginModel.clsSidebarMenu>(data);
    }
}

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>@ViewData["Title"] - RazorPageIdentity</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" asp-append-version="true" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/RazorPageIdentity.styles.css" asp-append-version="true" />
</head>

//........

//display the data
 <div>
        @if(modelList.MenuItems!=null)
        {
            foreach(var item in modelList.MenuItems)
            {
                 @item.id
                 @item.Group_Code
                //....
            }
        }            
    </div>

//.......
```

Comment: It shows the Error          InvalidOperationException: Could not create an instance of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.HttpContext'. Model bound complex types must not be abstract or value types and must have a parameterless constructor. Record types must have a single primary constructor. Alternatively, set the 'HttpContext' property to a non-null value in the 'Bizmagnet.Models.clsSidebarMenu' constructor.

Comment: I try this in my code and it works fine, Where does this error message appear? Can your provide the picture with the whole error message  in your question?

Comment: what is RazorPageIdentity?  is it your Project name? because i have made some changes here..i am very beginner in dot net core

Comment: yes, It's my project Name.  For testing convenience, I write two classes(`clsGEN_GROUP_MENU`,`clsSidebarMenu`) in PageModel directly, So in `_Layout.cshtml`. It is `var modelList = new {your project name}.Pages.{your pagemodel name}.clsSidebarMenu();`

Comment: If you write these classes(`clsGEN_GROUP_MENU`,`clsSidebarMenu`) In other places. For example , I create a folder called `Models` and I write these two classes in it, In `_LayOut.cshtml`, It is `var modelList = new {your project name}.Models.clsSidebarMenu();`. Finally, Don't forget add `[BindProperty]
    public clsSidebarMenu model { get; set; }


    [BindProperty]
    public clsGEN_GROUP_MENU cgm { get; set; }
` in your pagemodel

Comment: I have Added Model as Separate Class Library and I made some changes in _layout.cshtml as you said but it again shown Error, I will added images along with this.

Comment: What I have made is my Project Name is Template, But Each Model is Added in a Class Library called Bizmagnet.Models

Comment: What I have made is my Project Name is Template, But Each Model is Added in a Class Library called Bizmagnet.Models and Repositories Added As Another Class Library Called Bizmagnet.Services

Comment: can you provide a picture with Project structure？

Comment: did you see it in Answer Section I have Added an Image

Comment: When i remove `[BindProperty]` from the Code it is working but not getting data in _Layout.cshtml

Comment: I sorry there is no picture in your question.

Comment: How can I Add Picture here?? Can you Provide your Email ID let me Share the Images

Comment: You can Edit your question to add a picture.

Comment: Okay I have Added Image in Question it shows Project Structure, Please Take a look

Comment: I move my classes to the class library, But it still work well...  So Which line of code gives the error ?

Comment: Did you get the Data in Layout?? when I remove the `[BindProperty]` the Error is gone but it did not get Any data, that means it show Empty

Comment: it all works fine. you can edit your question to show the code after you changed.

Comment: I have Added Updated layout.cshtml image please take a look and let me know what is the wrong which I have made?

Comment: Hi, @NOUFAL KP I need you provide the picture with error message, I need to know whitch line of code cause the error.

Comment: Hi @Xinran Now I have Added Error Screen Also Along with the Code Please take Look, But one thing I notice that when i remove `[BindProperty]` the Error is gone , but what happened is it does not getting any data in `ModelList`